# Lottie anim does not play to the end. How to fix?

Tags: animation, android-animation, lottie

I have such lottie anim

```
https://dropmefiles.com/uweF8
```

You can check it on Lottie preview web site

```
https://lottiefiles.com/preview
```

In preview this file is working well

But if you will try to add this anim to the project like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/animation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
    app:lottie_loop="false"
    app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/heart"
    app:lottie_scale="1.2"
    tools:background="@color/black_30_alpha"
    tools:layout_height="200dp"
    tools:layout_width="match_parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

So you will have such result

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

And you can see that the animation does not meet the end.

What am I doing wrong?

I have tried to add this line in the code

```
mAnimHeart.setMaxProgress(1f);
```

But the result is the same

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in Lottie 3.0
https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/issues/1034

Answer (score 0):

In official [Lottie app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.airbnb.lottie) last frame of this json file is same as yours. So it looks like something wrong with that file. Maybe Lottie team doesn't add support for some features on android. Or maybe it is just bug. You can open issue on thier [github repository](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/issues).

[image]